# Is the variance of a random variable greater than the probability of it exceeding 1 in absolute value?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to prove a result in mathematical statistics, and I have been able to reduce it to this seemingly intuitive statement: given that $\mathrm{E}(\theta) =0$,

$$\mathrm{Var}(\theta) > P(|\theta| \geq 1)$$

I say that it seems intuitive because as the likelihood of a centered RV exceeding $1$ in absolute value increases, it should have a greater spread and thus a greater variance.  Is this in fact true? Can it easily be proven? Thanks so much.

Comment: Given -1 and 1 with equal probability, you have a variance of 1 while the right hand side is 1.

Comment: **Hint:** You can use Chebyshev´s Inequality

$$P[|X-\mu|>k]<\frac{Var(X)}{k^2}$$

Comment: @callculus Thank you so much, that was what I needed. I appreciate it.

Comment: @VanLatimer You´re welcome.